# How to ensure the 'correct' variable is used in a loop with anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

We have followed [Tom Anthony's tutorial](http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/geocoding-uk-postcodes-with-google-map-api/) to calculate a geocode from a UK postcode to plot a marker on a Google Map. This has worked fine, but now we wish to add a popup when you click on a location. So we updated our function to place a marker and original usePointFromPostcode code to take in a description:

```
function usePointFromPostcode(postcode, description, callbackFunction) {

  localSearch.setSearchCompleteCallback(null, 
    function() {

      if (localSearch.results[0]) {    
        var resultLat = localSearch.results[0].lat;
        var resultLng = localSearch.results[0].lng;
        var point = new GLatLng(resultLat,resultLng);
        callbackFunction(point, description);
      }else{
        alert("Postcode not found!");
      }
    });  

  localSearch.execute(postcode + ", UK");
}
// loop through the array of postcodes to output markers
for(var i=0; i<postcodes; i++) {
    usePointFromPostcode(postcodes[i], descriptions[i], placeMarkerAtPoint);
}
```

However, whilst the page loads without error, the markers all have the same description - that of the last item in the array. I believe this is due to a closure, or rather a lack of one, but am unable to hack out the solution. How can we get the descriptions in sync with the points?

Comment: The problem is that the loop does not wait until one of the `localSearch.execute` calls finished. The loop will end before the first call to `localSearch.execute` finishes. That also means that the `SearchCompleteCallback` for all searches will be the last one set. I don't know whether there is a solution for this, because it seems there can be only **one** callback.

Comment: The only thing I could imagine is that you create a map and use a property of the search result to identify a postcode and look up the corresponding data in the map.

Answer (score 0):

If localsearch.execute initiates a search but returns before the search is complete, then that would explain the behaviour.  Two possible solutions.  Create a separate GlocalSearch object for each query or delay issuing the second query until the first is complete, etc.

I don't know enough about the GlocalSearch class to say if the former is sensible. If it is, you presumably will have several searches running in parallel that may finish in arbitrary order.

To do the later:  Alter your callback to set a global flag *done* to true. Before initiating the first search, set *done* to false. After initiating the first search, set a timeout. The code executed by the timeout does the following: if *done* is now true, it sets *done* to false and initiates the second search.  Otherwise, it simply repeats the same timeout. And of course this sort of thing repeats until all searches are complete, at which point the time out code initiates whatever you want to do after that loop.  See http://www.ehow.com/how_4847411_simulate-whilesleep-loop-javascript.html for a short article that may be helpful.